# Unit tests for FastAPI - how to use breakpoints?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytest, fastapi

I have a code base that is using FastAPI. The unit tests use the `TestClient` as recommended in the [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/).

When debugging with VS Code, I add breakpoints to the code of my routes. However the debugger does not stop at the breakpoints.

Example here:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_main():
    x = 1 + 1  # Breakpoint added here - Does not work
    return {"msg": x}


client = TestClient(app)


def test_read_main():
    response = client.get("/")  # Breakpoint added here - Does work
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"msg": "Hello World"}
```

How can I get FastAPI to stop on breakpoints for unit tests? The docs mention [debugging](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/), but this is only for when the uvicorn server is running, and not with the `TestClient`.

Comment: try put import pdb;pdb.set_trace() in the code where you want to code to stop, and run the test case

Comment: You can try to set `"justMyCode"` in `launch.json` to **true**

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. For me, the solution had nothing to do with fastapi, but more with pytest-cov. Coverage interfered with debugging, and in my cfg file for pytest I had some options to produce a coverage report by default. Removing them solved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

Add the following codes to your `launch.json`:

```
"justMyCode": true,
```

Comment: that is not a setting in `settings.json` but instead in `launch.json`, I believe

Comment: @SoftwareThings Sorry, it's a writing error. Did this works if you added it to your `launch.json`? I've edited my answer.